# Pandas Groupby date index and count values in list of integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data which is a date index that has date range between '2014-08-22' and '2014-08-28' and one column with list of integers. I am trying to figure out a nice Pandas method for just grouping the numbers by date. Desired Result also below.

Date:

```
                                                                                values
date                                                                                        
2014-08-22                 [179, 187, 188, 190, 194, 198, 2, 226, 26, 311, 322, 325, 341, 6]
2014-08-22                 [179, 187, 188, 190, 194, 198, 2, 226, 26, 311, 322, 325, 341, 6]
2014-08-22  [167, 172, 178, 189, 198, 2, 20, 211, 212, 22, 274, 276, 287, 318, 321, 326, 48]
2014-08-23  [167, 172, 178, 189, 198, 2, 20, 211, 212, 22, 274, 276, 287, 318, 321, 326, 48]
2014-08-23  [167, 172, 178, 189, 198, 2, 20, 211, 212, 22, 274, 276, 287, 318, 321, 326, 48]
```

Desired pivot/groupby/crosstab Output:

```
      2014-08-22  2014-08-23
179       2           0
167       1           2
etc...
```

I know how to create a dict with the counts of occurrence as below but not sure how to group it by the index

```
from collections import Counter
values_list = list(chain.from_iterable(df['values']))
Counter(values_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach.

```
# expand lists of data into into columns
t = df['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, index=x))
t = t.fillna(0) #Filled by 0

# sum observations across days and transpose 
t.groupby(level=0).sum().T
```

Comment: very slick. Thank you.